# How to deal with image lazy loading when you have a SSR web app?

Tags: angular, image, seo, server-side-rendering

So, I read a bunch of articles and Google docs about lazy loading images in a proper way nowadays, and found this solution:

- Use the newer `loading="lazy"` in `<img />` tags where it's supported
- Fallback to the Intersection Observer where it is not

So far so good, but when I am delivering my web app with server-side rendering (in my case an Angular 8 app with ANgular Universal enabled), and I can't verify which browser my client uses when rendering, just when the app is rendered and then the lazy loading doesn't work.

I am using this great approach from Natanel: [Link](https://netbasal.com/lazy-load-images-in-angular-with-two-lines-of-code-beb13cd5a1c4)

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: 'img' })
export class LazyImgDirective {
  constructor({ nativeElement }: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>) {
    const supports = 'loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype;

    if (supports) {
      nativeElement.setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that this if is always falsy in server.

Answer (score 1):

images will still be downloaded as a separate http calls, so logic on the server won't work as you probably expect. what to do really depends on how do you handle the "unsupported" case.

case 1: you want to just leave the image as non lazy. If so - just add the attribute when this logic is used on the server environment. for newer browsers - these images will be lazy. for older browsers - your images will be loaded just as simple images, just the same as you directive logic.

case 2: you want to fallback to `IntersectionObserver`. In this case just skip the logic in this directive when running on server. it will be handled on client.

Comment: Just to confirm, in case 1 I would always set `loading="lazy"` on the server ? And this would not lead to any problems in browsers that don't have this implementation? I will test this today.

Comment: @rogerdossantos - yes, I think that's what @Andrei meant. Arbitrary attributes work just fine (in fact, Angular uses all sort of weird attributes itself), most browsers will be happy to ignore them (I doubt that they are valid HTML, if you care about that). Netanel probably chose to use a directive to have every image in the application lazily loaded without needing to manually add `loading="lazy"` to each one. A directive also allows for an easy fallback. Sadly, using an IO fallback with SSR does not work (Case 2) because the browser will load all images before the app is hydrated...

Comment: Hi! Just to update you guys, I ended up using the Intersection Observer, which works really well with data-src attr. Actually, I wrote a blog post about it in https://www.rogersantos.dev/ and I will translate it into English as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Here is the blog post explaining the usage of Intersection Observer: https://rogerio-dos-santos.com/lazy-loading-images-angular/